# how can I fire the mouse click button again and again using angular if I click and hold a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="rotate(true)">
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc" style="color:blue"></i>
    </button>
```

How can  I call the rotate function in my controller again and again after an interval of say 500 msec until the user clicks and holds the button?

Comment: You can call particular function on regular intervals using setInterval, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a combination of the ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup directie interval service you can create this functionality.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
        ng-mousedown="startRotate(true)" ng-mouseup="endRotate()" ng-mouseleave="endRotate()" >
    <i class="fa fa-sort-asc" style="color:blue"></i>
</button>
```

in the startrotate function you create an interval that calls the rotate function every x time. In the endRotate you call the cancel function on the interval you created in the start function.

Edit: you also need ng-mouseleave because the ng-mouseup is never registered if you move the mouse off the button while the mouse button is down.

Documentation:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousedown

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseup

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: You beat me to it :( Here is a **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/g2CF2/)** I prepared for...demonstration

Comment: Nice example though, using your example I discovered that you also need ng-mouseleave. i altered you example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7vbY4/2/